# Is Xchat available in the Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 20.10 or later?

Tags: xchat

I would like to install Xchat, the IRC client, on Ubuntu 21.04. These are the instructions I find on various parts of the web, to run:

```
sudo apt install xchat
```

However, when I run this, I get this error:

```
Package xchat is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'xchat' has no installation candidate
```

In seems that the package `xchat` is no longer available in the Ubuntu universe repositories in Ubuntu 20.10 or later. Is that right? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xchat

`xchat` isn't maintained and `hexchat` is generally preferred

`xchat` requires python2 (EOL) and hasn't been ported to python3.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xchat

Comment: I'm slightly amused that hexchat started off as a windows port (as xchat-wdk) and is now the 'preferred' xchat fork.

Comment: `hexchat` itself is old & rather deprecated...   It's GTK2 based which shows it's age (GTK3 is the current standard with GNOME moving to GTK4).  Most users will likely have moved to newer IRC clients...  me I still use `hexchat` though as many addons for it rely on `python2` (just as with `xchat`) my reason for sticking with it are mostly I'm lazy..  I wonder if we'll still have it in 22.04 & later; it's days numbered like LXDE & other GTK2 tools to when `gimp` is fully GTK3, & GTK2 gets removed from debian/ubuntu repositories; the question is *when* will this occur, not *if* in my opinion